# Merge two Apache Avro schemas containing a common array using jq

Tags: shell, jq

I've got two Apache Avro schemas (essentially JSON) - one being a "common" part across many schemas and another one as an . Looking for a way to merge them in a shell script.

base.avsc

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

schema1.avsc

```
{
  "name": "schema1",
  "namespace": "test",
  "doc": "Test schema",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "property1",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null,
      "doc": "Schema 1 specific field"
    }
  ]
}
```

`jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' base.avsc schema1.avsc` doesn't merge the array for me:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "property1",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null,
      "doc": "Schema 1 specific field"
    }
  ],
  "name": "schema1",
  "namespace": "test",
  "doc": "Test schema"
}
```

I don't expect to have same keys in the "fields" array. And `"type": "record",` could be moved into schema1.avsc if that makes it easier.

An expected result should be something like this (the order of the keys doesn't make a difference)

```
{
  "name": "schema1",
  "namespace": "test",
  "doc": "Test schema",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
      {
        "name": "property1",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ],
        "default": null,
        "doc": "Schema 1 specific field"
      },
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can't figure out how to write an expression in jq for what I want.

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: sorry, forgot to include the expected result! updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an addition (`+`) operator to perform a union of records from both the files and combine the common record `fields` from both the files as

```
jq -s '.[0] as $o1 | .[1] as $o2 | ($o1 + $o2) |.fields = ($o2.fields + $o1.fields) ' base.avsc schema1.avsc
```

Answer adopted from [pkoppstein's comment](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/502#issuecomment-50067368) on this GitHub post [Merge arrays in two json files.](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/502)

The [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) says this under the addition operator `+`

> `Objects` are added by merging, that is, inserting all the key-value pairs from both objects into a single combined object. If both objects contain a value for the same key, the object on the right of the `+` wins. (For recursive merge use the `*` operator.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a concise solution that avoids "slurping":

```
jq --argfile base base.avsc '
  $base + .
  | .fields += ($base|.fields)
' schema1.avsc
```

Or you could go with brevity:

```
jq -s '
  .[0].fields as $f | add | .fields += $f
' base.avsc schema1.avsc
```

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative solution, you may consider handling hierarchical json using a walk-path based unix utility **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**.

the ask here is mere a recursive merge, which with `jtc` looks like this:

```
bash $ <schema1.avsc jtc -mi base.avsc 
{
   "doc": "Test schema",
   "fields": [
      {
         "default": null,
         "doc": "Schema 1 specific field",
         "name": "property1",
         "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "id",
         "type": "string"
      }
   ],
   "name": "schema1",
   "namespace": "test",
   "type": "record"
}
bash $
```

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` - shell cli tool for JSON operations